# Lehmann primality test

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

How to calculate final probability that a given number is prime after 1000 iterations, when using Lehmann primality test ?

Comment: it is called the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

Comment: Assuming you actually mean Miller-Rabin, a basic reference is
*Average case error estimates for the strong probable prime test
Ivan Damgård, Peter Landrock and Carl Pomerance.
Math. Comp. 61 (1993), 177-194*, available as 
http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1189518-9/S0025-5718-1993-1189518-9.pdf

The probability depends on the bit-size and the repeat count.
Note that for almost all tests in the wild a repeat count of $1000$
is ridiculous overkill.

Comment: @ user1952009 and @gammatester - Thanks for your help, Actually I dont know these two are same or not. ( Miller-Rabin and Lehmann), and I think gammatester reference is too much maths for me. Are there any easily understnad answer, Highly appreciate your help.